# Django - Annotate with Case/When/Value and related objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the two following models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()


class Vote(models.Model):
    UP_VOTE = 0
    DOWN_VOTE = 1

    VOTE_TYPES = (
        (UP_VOTE, "Up vote"),
        (DOWN_VOTE, "Down vote"),
    )

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="votes")
    vote_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=VOTE_TYPES)
```

I would like to have a score property on Post that returns the sum of the values of the votes to that post, counting votes with UP_VOTE type as 1 and those with DOWN_VOTE as -1.

This is what I’ve tried:

```
    # inside Post
    @property
    def score(self):
        return (
            self.votes.all()
            .annotate(
                value=Case(
                    When(vote_type=Vote.DOWN_VOTE, then=Value(-1)),
                    When(vote_type=Vote.UP_VOTE, then=Value(1)),
                    default=Value("0"),
                    output_field=models.SmallIntegerField(),
                )
            )
            .aggregate(Sum("value"))["value__sum"]
        )
```

However, this yields `None`. More specifically, without dereferencing `["value__sum"]`, this returns `{'value__sum': None}`.

Is using Case-When-Value the correct approach to my use case? If so, what’s wrong with the code I posted?

Comment: Could be because your default is a string, not an integer. Also, you would save yourself the trouble of using `Case` and `When` if your model choice had `-1` as the down vote option!

Comment: Are you sure your Post has votes assigned to it? Aggregate result in None if queryset is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of an empty set will be `NULL`/`None` by default. As of [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0), you can work with the [**`default=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#default):

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

@property
def score(self):
    return self.votes.aggregate(total=Sum(-2*F('vote_type') + 1, default=0))['total']
```

Prior to [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0), you can work with [**`Coalesce`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce):

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

@property
def score(self):
    return self.votes.aggregate(
        total=Coalesce(Sum(-2*F('vote_type') + 1), Value(0))
    )['total']
```

although in this simple case, you can just replace `None` by `0` at the Django/Python layer:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

@property
def score(self):
    return self.votes.aggregate(total=Sum(-2*F('vote_type') + 1))['total'] or 0
```

It might be better to use the "score" of a vote as value, so:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    UP_VOTE = 1
    DOWN_VOTE = -1
    # …
    vote_type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=VOTE_TYPES)
```

This will make the aggregation logic simpler, and will make it easier to later allow for example voting +5, -10, etc.

Comment: You're right that I was missing a default value. That fixed it. As for directly using the value of vote_type: I like decoupling the type (conceptually an enum constant) from the score it assigns: one day I might add more vote types (think reactions) that yield the same score. A bonus question: how would I use this aggregation inside a queryset of Posts? For example if I wanted to order by the score, how would I need to change the code I posted?

Comment: @SamueleB.: use `.annotate(..)` instead, so `Post.objects.annotate(score=...).order_by('-score')`. The field names should then use `votes__` as prefix, so `votes__vote_type` for example.